# How to add text in image from database in laravel

Tags: laravel

[How to add text in image from database  in laravel][1]

public function creatememb(Request $request){

```
    $file = $request->file('image');

    $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $cid = 'SELECT id FROM `memebs`';

//    $primaryKey = 'cid';


    $path = 'upload/'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;
    $img = Image::make($file);
    $img->text($cid, 120, 100, function($font) {  
        $font->size(68);  
        $font->color('#4285F4');  
        $font->align('center');  
        $font->valign('bottom');  
        $font->angle(0);  
    });  
    $output;

    $img->save(public_path($path));

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['image'] = $path;
   
    return $this->create($input);
}
```

This is the text of code of my repository

Comment: welcome to so, your question is not clear & is not as per mentioned in [how to ask questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

> 

we can add text as a watermark on an image in Laravel.

We need to install intervention/image package and then we will create one simple route to adding image watermark.
Step:1 Install intervention/image using the following command:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

After complete installation, you need to add providers and aliases. config>app.php. Open the app.php file  in your code editor  and add two lines in the providers and aliases array like this:
config/app.php

```
‘providers’ => [
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
]
‘aliases’ => [
 ‘Image’ => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
]
```

Step 2: Publish configuration using the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

Let’s create a controller named WatermarkController. Type this command to create the controller:
Step 3: Create a Controller using the following command:

```
php artisan make:controller WatermarkController
```

After creating that open the controller from app/Http/Controllers in your code editor and paste this code:

add namespace

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

add method

```
public function addWatermark(){
   $img = Image::make(public_path('images/demo.png'));
    // add text from database 
   $img->text('add data what you want.', 120, 100);

   $img->save(public_path('images/demo-new.png')); 
   
   dd('Watermark create successfully.');
   
   // create Image from file
    $img = Image::canvas(10, 10, '#fff');
    
    // write text
    $img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
    $img->save(public_path('images/demo-new1.png')); 

    // write text at position
    $img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);

    // use callback to define details
    $img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
        $font->file('foo/bar.ttf');
        $font->size(24);
        $font->color('#fdf6e3');
        $font->align('center');
        $font->valign('top');
        $font->angle(45);
    });
    
    $img->save(public_path('images/demo-new2.png')); 

    // draw transparent text
    $img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
        $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
    });
    
    $img->save(public_path('images/demo-new3.png')); 
    dd('Watermark create successfully.');
}
```

Step:4 Create Route

Here, I will create a simple route and add a watermark to the image.

Route::get('add-watermark', 'WatermarkController@addWatermark')

**Done!**

For more information about creating a watermark, follow this link.
And More: http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: I have also using image intervention But I need to print my Image id in image and the image id is diffrent every time fatch from database

Comment: like meesho, monisho reselling app

Comment: // add image id from database 
   $img->text($image->id, 120, 100);

Comment: But which one Query Should I Run in $image Variable